# train() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target_train'

Tags: python, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

This is my code and I'm getting an error. pnn is a network from neupy library in python

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.33,random_state=42)
pnn.train(X_train,y_train)
y_predicted = pnn.predict(X_test)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_predicted)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-30-e70a297d47a5> in <module>
    ----> 1 pnn.train(X_train,y_train)
          2 
          3 y_predicted = pnn.predict(X_test)
          4 metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_predicted)
    
    TypeError: train() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target_train'
```

Comment: pnn is a network in http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.rbfn.pnn.html

Comment: You didn't add any code regarding the `pnn` object so unfortunately that doesn't help

Comment: about print(type(pnn)) the answer is <class 'neupy.core.config.ConfigABCMeta'>

Comment: I don't think that the `PNN` code you posted is relevant.
What is relevant is what is referred to in your code when you call `pnn.train`.
It seems that `pnn` in your code is a reference to the `PNN` class, and not to a `PNN` object

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `pnn` object is not initialized. instead you are referencing the PNN class of neupy.

look at this example:

```py
pnn = algorithms.PNN(std=10, verbose=False)  # <-- initialized
print(type(pnn))  
# output is: neupy.algorithms.rbfn.pnn.PNN

pnn = algorithms.PNN  # <-- not initialized
print(type(pnn))  
# output is like in your case: neupy.core.config.ConfigABCMeta
```

if your `pnn` object was initialized properly, the type of the object would have been `neupy.algorithms.rbfn.pnn.PNN` and not `neupy.core.config.ConfigABCMeta`

You posted [This link](http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.rbfn.pnn.html) in the comments, there is an example there that you might want to follow, and it should solve your issue

Comment: but the problem is I think about the array in X-train and Y_train, I dont know how to match them in order to work and get the answer.TypeError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1099,100,100,3) (100,109900,3)

Comment: That's not related to your original question, you should ask another question if you encountered a new issue.

Comment: Don't edit the question to ask another question, that's not useful to anyone trying to solve the issues you were trying to solve